# How to call the field name and table name with two words in ado-SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

```
select officer code ,total from [$staff record ]
```

Here is the sample SQL.

Officer code is one of the field name in excel with two words.

Staff record is one of the table name in excel with two words .

**What is the correct syntax to call these two items without changing the excel structure ?[image]

## update

It is not working for using [officer code]

Comment: Do you mean `select [officer code], ....`?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the excel column structure? Or is it from a SQL database you wan't to pull in some data?

Comment: @McBoman photo updated

Comment: @jarlh please see update

Comment: Add sample table data as text (not a picture), and also add the expected result!

Comment: @jarlh for ADO , it is unable to run the SQL because of the wrong data structure .Now , i cant run the ADO in VBA editor . if the statement is valid ,i can run the sql . I just want to run the SQL .Now ,pop out error [expected number 2]

Comment: `Select [officer code] from ['staff record$']` should work.

Comment: @Axel Richter [officer code] is not okay . i guess officer code is different from officer (enter) code (excel field name ) .I make a try to test officer (space) code using `[officer code] .It works .

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** clear from the picture, what content cell `A1` actually contains. It is formatted as "Wrap Text". So it can contain `officer code` or `officer  code` or `officer   code` with 1, 2, 3, ... blanks between `officer`and `code`. The cell wraps this text if it is small enough. Or it can contain `officer\ncode` or `officer\n code` or `officer \ncode` in any possible combinations. So you should detect at first what content cell `A1` actually contains.

If it is `officer\ncode`:

You really should not have field names containing line feeds with ADO. But if you have you can use an underscore instead of the line feed within the field name.

Example:

If the Excel sheet name is `staff record` and the column header is

```
officer
code
```

where there is a line feed between officer and code,

then the following select should work:

```
Select [officer_code] from ['staff record$']
```

The annoying thing with this is that one cannot see in the view whether there are not even more weird things. For example if there is a space after `officer` before the line feed, then it is `[officer _code]`.

So, you really should not have field names containing line feeds.

Comment: Is line feed = (keyboard-enter) ?

Comment: In Excel cells the line feed is 0x0A hexadecimal and must be entered using [Alt]+[Enter] (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Wrap-text-in-a-cell-2a18cff5-ccc1-4bce-95e4-f0d4f3ff4e84?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc356986254).